# Recover deleted app data

Tags: root-access, data-recovery, app-data, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I'm having some trouble with an app, it is an app for a service provided by my local bank. Apparently for security purposes it is not on the Play Store and when you subscribe they send you an SMS with credentials and app download link.

I downloaded the app and used it. First time you launch it asks for credentials and activates your account, no login Activity, just the Activation Activity and then it goes straight to usual interface every time.

So I accidentally deleted the app data (meant to delete cache) and now every time I launch it I have to activate my account, which won't activate because it is already activated !!

I spoke to the bank customer service and they said I can only cancel subscription first before they send new credentials which is supposed to be done from within the app. So I'm stuck unless I can recover the app data. They are charging me for the service by the way.

I am using a rooted Galaxy Note 8.0, is there any way I can recover the data ? Preferably for free?

Comment: Your going to have to follow the way they want this done, which is uninstall and reinstall. Look at it this way, as inconvenient as this may be, they are keeping your banking information safe (which is in your best interest) this way. Otherwise __anybody__ could access your banking data. *That being said*, there is an app called __UNDELETER__ from an XDA developer (sorry not on a good connection to provide you the link) that could work, provided you haven't had the data overwritten.  That means don't add anything new, update, or anything else that might corrupt the erased data.

Comment: The thing is their way is just checking whether my data is correct or not and once they find that the account is ok they think my problem is solved, apparently they hired some dev for the app and it's not their responsibility to fix his mistake and I don't blame them, an app with no login interface and just activation the first time with an error if the account is already activated? That's really stupid imo, secure if the bank knows what's going on but not like this !!! I'm switching to another bank anyways.  Thanks a lot for your answer,  I know it's the only one but I thought maybe it wasn't

Comment: Finally did it ! They said they hadn't encountered this situation before and customer service is seperated rrom tech support so no one I spoke to knew what to do and they wouldn't let me speak directly to tech support. Had to chek with my software engineering colleagues on how it might work and eventually tricked them into cancelling the service and subscribed again a few days later. Apparently they only hand out credentials once per account so they had to completely delete it. I knew alresdy that it would come to them but looks like they have this policy about not  letting customers leave :D

Comment: Glad you got to work. Kudos for thinking "around" the box.